# `data.table` global search - filter rows given pattern match in `any` column

Tags: r, regex, data.table

Is there any already existing convenience function that would filter rows in the `data.table`, given search pattern, **looking inside all columns**?

```
names(DT)

[1] "Name" "LongName" "SomeOtherCol" "NumericCol" "bar" "foo"
```

Something like this, generalised for any number of columns:

```
DT[Name %like% pattern | LongName %like% pattern | SomeOtherCol %like% pattern | bar %like% pattern | foo %like% pattern]
```

Comment: +1 are you trying to replicate the datatables feature? (I mean the jQuery plug-in)

Comment: @Michele not familiar with `datatables`, but [example here](https://datatables.net/) has "Search" text input field, which pretty much does the same thing as above

Comment: ... the link you put is exactly `datatables`

Comment: thank god for the internetz :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to loop through the columns, apply your regex, which'll return a logical data.table back. You can use `rowSums` to get the rows then.

```
dt <- data.table(a=c("Aa1","bb","1c"),b=c("A1","a1","1C"), c=letters[1:3])
# "a1" is the pattern to search for
ldt <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("a1", x, perl=TRUE))] 
dt[rowSums(ldt)>0]
#      a  b c
# 1: Aa1 A1 a
# 2:  bb a1 b
```

Comment: If you've too many columns, a faster way, but less memory efficient would be to convert the `data.table` to `matrix` and then apply `grep` - as it'll apply it on the whole matrix directly.

Comment: Many thanks @Arun. Would you reasonably expect this to be faster compared to the approach whereas I'd first append strings to arrive at the expression similar to `a %like% pattern | b %like% pattern |...` (or even using directly `grepl`) and then `DT[eval(combined.expression)]` ? I was about to build that approach, but I'd rather trust your informed opinion on this whether it is worth the effort

Comment: I'm guessing yours'll be faster (as it avoids `rowSums`).. at least on larger `data.tables`.

Comment: I accepted your solution as slightly faster in benchmark test (see my answer) and arguably more succinct.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 3:**

First construct the logical `grep` `expression` appending all columns. Then `eval` the overall expression in one go:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c("a1","bb","1c"),b=c("A1","BB","1C"))

search.data.table <- function(x, pattern) {
  nms <- names(x)
  string <- eval(expression(paste0("grepl('",
                                   pattern, 
                                   "', ",
                                   nms,",
                                   ignore.case=TRUE, perl=FALSE)",
                                   collapse = " | ")))
  x[eval(as.call(parse(text=string))[[1]])]
}

search.data.table(dt, "a1")
#      a  b c
# 1: Aa1 A1 a
# 2:  bb a1 b
```

**Benchmarking**

```
# functions

Raffael <- function(x, pattern) {
# unfortunately this implementation throws an error so I can't run the benchmark test. 
# Any help?
  combined <- apply(x,1,function(r) paste(r,collapse="/%/"))
  grepped <- grepl(pattern,apply(x,1,function(r) paste(r,collapse="/")))
  x[grepped,]
}

Arun <- function(x, pattern) {
  ldt <- x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl(pattern, x, perl=TRUE, ignore.case=TRUE))] 
  x[rowSums(ldt)>0]
}

DanielKrizian <- function(x, pattern) {
  nms <- names(x)
  string <- eval(expression(paste0("grepl('", pattern, "', ",nms,", ignore.case=TRUE,      perl=FALSE)",collapse = " | ")))
  x[eval(as.call(parse(text=string))[[1]])]
}

# generate 1000 x 1000 benchmark data.table

require(data.table)
expr <- quote(paste0(sample(c(LETTERS,tolower(LETTERS),0:9),12, replace=T)
                 ,collapse=""))
set.seed(1)
BIGISH <- data.table(matrix(replicate(1000*1000,eval(expr)),nrow = 1000))
object.size(BIGISH) # 68520912 bytes

# test

benchmark(
  DK <- DanielKrizian(BIGISH,"qx"),
  A <- Arun(BIGISH,"qx"),
  replications=100)
```

**Results**

```
                               test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2           A <- Arun(BIGISH, "qx")          100   57.72    1.000     51.95     0.44         NA        NA
1 DK <- DanielKrizian(BIGISH, "qx")          100   59.28    1.027     53.72     0.50         NA        NA

identical(DK,A)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: When you do add benchmarks, please add benchmarking results on relatively bigger data.

Comment: @Arun, edited the test data in, waiting to get home and run. suggestions for better data welcome

Comment: @Arun, changed the data size to 1000 rows x 1000 cols

Answer (score 2):

I am not betting that this is the best way to do it. But it serves the purpose:

```
> dt <- data.table(a=c("a1","bb","1c"),b=c("A1","BB","1C"))
> dt
    a  b
1: a1 A1
2: bb BB
3: 1c 1C

> combined <- apply(dt,1,function(r) paste(r,collapse="/%/"))
> combined
[1] "a1/%/A1" "bb/%/BB" "1c/%/1C"

> grepped <- grepl("[a-z][0-9]",apply(dt,1,function(r) paste(r,collapse="/")))
> grepped
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> dt[grepped,]
    a  b
1: a1 A1
```

The "/%/" would have to be something that is not relevant to the pattern and reliably separates columns.

The steps can be combined into a single expression of course.

Comment: thanks for some inspiration, I will try to come up with solution native to `data.table` for better performance

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, in terms of speed. Depending on the size of the `data.table`, `paste` could be quite time consuming.

Comment: I somehow couldn't get your solution to work when I tried to benchmark for speed. Please have a look at the implementation (function "Raffael") in my answer below.